# Oracle script through command line - How to avoid Prompting for Time etc?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have taken a SQL dump as script from `Jdeveloper` and trying to create database at other place by  running the oracle SQL script through command line.

When executing, at some place in the script, it is prompting for values like `Enter value for time:`  and `Enter Value for p:`.

What could be the reason and how to prevent this when taking dump. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the beginning of the scripts:

```
   set define off;
```

Your data probably contains the '&' character and it want to substitute input variables.

Comment: Thank you . It worked. I also did this in other way by defining Escape char using  : set escape \ and using \ to eacape &